# Want to push to another view controller from a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, swift4

**What do i have**: A view controller (WhereViewController) with some "child/container"-views. One is a collection view (typeCollectionView). the WhereViewController is embedded in a navigationController:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOQyJ.png)

```
class WhereViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var progressContainerView: ProgressBarView = {
    let containerView = ProgressBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return containerView
}()

let questionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()

    label.text = "question?"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.font = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Italic", size: 14)
    label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.33, green:0.33, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
}()

let typeCollectionView: WhereCollectionView = {
    let collectionView = WhereCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return collectionView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Schaden melden"

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    view.addSubview(progressContainerView)
    view.addSubview(questionLabel)
    view.addSubview(typeCollectionView)

    setupProgressContainerView()
    setupQuestionLabel()
    setupTypeCollectionView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func setupProgressContainerView() {
    progressContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    progressContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    progressContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    progressContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}

private func setupQuestionLabel() {
    questionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 22).isActive = true
    questionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    questionLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    questionLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
}

private func setupTypeCollectionView() {
    typeCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: questionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    typeCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    typeCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    typeCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

}

**Want am I trying to do:** Within the typeCollectionView: If an item is selected (didSelectItemAt) i want to push to the next viewController via navigationController of the WhereViewController. My typeCollectionView looks like:

```
class WhereCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var whereViewController: WhereViewController?

let label = ["x", "y", "z"]

override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    delegate = self
    dataSource = self

    self.register(WhereCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "WhereCollectionViewCell")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return label.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WhereCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! WhereCollectionViewCell

    cell.injureLabel.text = label[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 75)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

}

**I've tried** to give the whereViewController to the typeCollectionView:

```
let typeCollectionView: WhereCollectionView = {
    let collectionView = WhereCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.whereViewController = self 

    return tableView
}()
```

**But get:** Cannot assign value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> WhereViewController' to type 'WhereViewController?'

Could someone help me? or isn't it possible to "speak" with the navigationController from the collectionView (containerView)?

I do not use storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You should conform the **view controller** to the collection delegate methods and **not the collection view itself**.

Make `WhereViewController` conform to `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
class WhereViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

In `WhereViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, set up the delegate and the data source:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    typeCollectionView.dataSource = self
    typeCollectionView.delegate = self

    [...]
}
```

Comment: i've implemented the code, at: "(typeCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.delegate = self" i've got an error: "Value of type 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout' has no member 'delegate'" .

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use delegate to send message from `CollectionView` to 
`ViewController`.

Simple declare a protocol

```
protocol CustomDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(DidSelect : Int)
}
```

After that make an instance of `CustomDelegate` protocol in `WhereCollectionView` Class

```
class WhereCollectionView: UICollectionView {

weak var customDelegate:CustomDelegate?

}
```

and in `didSelect` methods fire the delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if let _del = customDelegate {
         _del.collectionView(DidSelect : IndexPath.row)
}

}
```

In `ViewController` there you are adding `collectionview` in `viewcontroller` set `delegate` to `self`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Schaden melden"

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

   typeCollectionView.customDelegate = self

    view.addSubview(progressContainerView)
    view.addSubview(questionLabel)
    view.addSubview(typeCollectionView)

    setupProgressContainerView()
    setupQuestionLabel()
    setupTypeCollectionView()
}
```

Also Implement the `Custom` delegate method in `ViewController`

```
func collectionView(DidSelect : Int) {
   /// from there you can do your job
}
```

Comment: I try to follow your code. At this point: weak var delegate:CustomDelegate? i got an error, saying: "Property 'delegate' with type 'CustomDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'UICollectionViewDelegate?'"; could you help?

Comment: You get this error UICollectionView already have delegate variable. Just change the name of CustomDelegate variable your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1) Add extension:

```
extension UIView {

   var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
      var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
      while parentResponder != nil {
         parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
         if parentResponder is UIViewController {
            return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
         }
      }

      return nil
   }
}
```

2) Now you can use:

```
parentViewController?.present(<ControllerName>, animated: true)
```

Hope it helps